# CakePHP, want to use the findById($my_id) instead of findById($id) but got error:

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

In my RedpCategory table I use cat_id as primaryKey, something like in my model below

### in RedpCategory model:

```
<?php
   App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
   class RedpCategory extends AppModel {
   public $useTable = 'redp_category';
   public $name = 'RedpCategory';
   public $primaryKey = 'cat_id';
//
//
}
```

### in my view:

```
public function view($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid redeem category'));
    }

    $redp_categories = $this->RedpCategory->findById($id);
    if (!$redp_categories) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid redeem category'));
    }
    $this->set('redp_categories', $redp_categories);
}
```

I got an error when I click on a category name link: "Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column
RedpCategory.id does not exist"

How can I solve with this problem?

Any answer will be appreciated.Thank you in advanced.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#findby

Comment: Thank you CBroe ! Actually, I saw this page previous time already, but not carefully read it, my bad! Now you make see it, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`findById()` will search for the literal 'id' field.

Try switching your find statement to:

```
$this->RedpCategory->findByCatId($id);
```

Edit: redacted incorrect information